Unable to purchase with Promotional Offer
I am trying to make the In-App Purchase promotional offer work. So I get the encoded signature, nonce, timestamp, and key identifier from our server. I create a SKPaymentDiscount object and set this to paymentDiscount of SKMutablePayment object.
On the first pop it shows the revised price as expected -> enter the password and continue -> after verification is successful: done -> Second pop-up: shows the following error Unable to Purchase Contact the developer for more information.

Note: updatedTransactions method not being called.
No matter how many times I try, it keeps giving me the same error. Unable to Purchase Contact the developer for more information. What can be done to resolve this issue. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks In Advance!
Node.JS code that generates the encoded signature.
exports.ValidatePromotionalOffer = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) =>{

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept");

    var appBundleID = req.body.appBundleID;
    var productIdentifier = req.body.productIdentifier;
    var offerIdentifier = req.body.offerIdentifier;
    var Username = req.body.applicationUsername;

    console.log("Body",req.body)

    var applicationUsername = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(Username).digest('hex');

    var currentDate = new Date()
    var timestamp = currentDate.getTime();

    var nonce = uuidv4();
    console.log("nonce",nonce)

    var keyID = getKeyID();
    console.log("keyID",keyID)
    
    var payload = appBundleID + '\u2063' +
                    keyID + '\u2063' +
                    productIdentifier + '\u2063' +
                    offerIdentifier + '\u2063' +
                    applicationUsername + '\u2063' +
                    nonce + '\u2063' +
                    timestamp;

    var keyString = getKeyStringForID();

    console.log("keyString",keyString)

    const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256')
                   .update(payload)
                   .sign(keyString, 'base64');

    console.log("sign",sign)

    res.status(200).send({"keyID": keyID, "nonce": nonce, "timestamp": timestamp, "signature": sign});


    function getKeyID(){

        return process.env.SUBSCRIPTION_OFFERS_KEY_ID;
    }

    function getKeyStringForID(){

        if(keyID == process.env.SUBSCRIPTION_OFFERS_KEY_ID){

            return process.env.SUBSCRIPTION_OFFERS_PRIVATE_KEY;
        }
        else{
            throw "Key Id not recognized";
            res.status(400).send('Invalid signature');
        }
    }

});

Code on the app side
func ValidatePromotionalOffer(productIdentifier: String, offerIdentifier: String, product: SKProduct){
        
        print("ValidatePromotionalOffer called")
        
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "appBundleID": "bundleid",
            "productIdentifier": productIdentifier,
            "offerIdentifier": offerIdentifier,
            "applicationUsername": username
        ]
        
        print("parameters",parameters)
        
        AF.request("https://us-central1-projectname.cloudfunctions.net/ValidatePromotionalOffer", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON{ response in
                let statuscode = response.response?.statusCode
                
                switch response.result{
                    
                case .success(let resultdata):
                    if(statuscode == 200) {
                        
                        print("successful")
                        
                        let jsonResult = JSON(response.value! as Any)
                        
                        print("response",jsonResult)
                        
                        let signature = jsonResult["signature"].stringValue
                        let keyID = jsonResult["keyID"].stringValue
                        let timestamp = jsonResult["timestamp"].numberValue
                        let nonce = UUID(uuidString: jsonResult["nonce"].stringValue)
                        
                        // Create offer
                        let discountOffer = SKPaymentDiscount(identifier: offerIdentifier, keyIdentifier: keyID, nonce: nonce!, signature: signature, timestamp: timestamp)

                        // Pass offer in completion block
                        //completion(discountOffer)
                        
                        //SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
                        self.buyProduct1(product: product, forUser: jsonResult["nonce"].stringValue, withOffer: discountOffer);
                            
                        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("SUCCESS EARLY FOR FIRST TIME 2")
                        
                        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                        
                        let jsonResult = JSON(response.value! as Any)
                        print("error response",jsonResult)

                    }
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("failure yes", error)
                    
                    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                }
                
        }
    }

public func buyProduct1(product: SKProduct, forUser usernameHash: String, withOffer discountOffer: SKPaymentDiscount) {

        // The original product being purchased.
        let payment = SKMutablePayment(product: product)

        // You must set applicationUsername to be the same as the one used to generate the signature.
        payment.applicationUsername = usernameHash

        // Add the offer to the payment.
        payment.paymentDiscount = discountOffer

        // Add the payment to the queue for purchase.
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }

