Accessing multiple promotional offers on a single subscription
I have 6 subscriptions in a subscription group. Each subscription has 2 active promotional offers configured. One is a 25% offer for a month, and another is a 50% offer for a month.
My doubt is, can users access both promotional offers in a single subscription? Not at a time
First 25% offer and then 50% offer


How do you make the offers available?  Are they introductory offers or promotional offers using a code? If the latter, do you provide individual codes or are they using a fixed promo code?

Hi @Paulw11, I am using the promotional offers shown in the picture above, not the introductory offers or Offer codes.

If they are reusable codes like "halfpricemonthl or "25off" then there is nothing to stop people who get the codes from using both of them in different months.

@Paulw11, I am a little confused when you mention codes. We are not sharing any codes with users, such as offer codes ("WELCOME50" and "DIWALISALE"). We create different promotional offers with different IDs in the console. On the app side, according to the conditions we call which promotional offer to apply.
Below is the link to implement promotional offers.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79192360/unable-to-purchase-with-promotional-offer

If you are sharing specific promotional offer codes then it is up to you to track whether a user has already been given an offer code and not give them any more if that is what you want.

Finally what you are saying is, that users can access multiple promotional offers on a single subscription

Yes. Only one introductory offer but multiple promotional offers
